# How does Firefox Inspector's Walker work?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, promise, firefox-developer-tools

In Firefox, at the start of modules/devtools/inspector/inspector-panel.js you see some references to a "walker", shown at the end of this snippet:

```
 ...

/**
 * Represents an open instance of the Inspector for a tab.
 * The inspector controls the highlighter, the breadcrumbs,
 * the markup view, and the sidebar (computed view, rule view
 * and layout view).
 *
 * Events:
 * - ready
 *      Fired when the inspector panel is opened for the first time and ready to
 *      use
 * - new-root
 *      Fired after a new root (navigation to a new page) event was fired by
 *      the walker, and taken into account by the inspector (after the markup
 *      view has been reloaded)
 * - markuploaded
 *      Fired when the markup-view frame has loaded
 * - layout-change
 *      Fired when the layout of the inspector changes
 * - breadcrumbs-updated
 *      Fired when the breadcrumb widget updates to a new node
 * - layoutview-updated
 *      Fired when the layoutview (box model) updates to a new node
 * - markupmutation
 *      Fired after markup mutations have been processed by the markup-view
 * - computed-view-refreshed
 *      Fired when the computed rules view updates to a new node
 * - computed-view-property-expanded
 *      Fired when a property is expanded in the computed rules view
 * - computed-view-property-collapsed
 *      Fired when a property is collapsed in the computed rules view
 * - rule-view-refreshed
 *      Fired when the rule view updates to a new node
 */
function InspectorPanel(iframeWindow, toolbox) {
  this._toolbox = toolbox;
  this._target = toolbox._target;
  this.panelDoc = iframeWindow.document;
  this.panelWin = iframeWindow;
  this.panelWin.inspector = this;
  this._inspector = null;

  this._onBeforeNavigate = this._onBeforeNavigate.bind(this);
  this._target.on("will-navigate", this._onBeforeNavigate);

  EventEmitter.decorate(this);
}

exports.InspectorPanel = InspectorPanel;

InspectorPanel.prototype = {
  /**
   * open is effectively an asynchronous constructor
   */
  open: function InspectorPanel_open() {
    return this.target.makeRemote().then(() => {
      return this._getWalker();
    }).then(() => {
      return this._getDefaultNodeForSelection();
    }).then(defaultSelection => {
      return this._deferredOpen(defaultSelection);
    }).then(null, console.error);
  },

  get inspector() {
    if (!this._target.form) {
      throw new Error("Target.inspector requires an initialized remote actor.");
    }
    if (!this._inspector) {
      this._inspector = InspectorFront(this._target.client, this._target.form);
    }
    return this._inspector;
  },

  _deferredOpen: function(defaultSelection) {
    let deferred = promise.defer();

    this.outerHTMLEditable = this._target.client.traits.editOuterHTML;

    this.onNewRoot = this.onNewRoot.bind(this);
    this.walker.on("new-root", this.onNewRoot);

    this.nodemenu = this.panelDoc.getElementById("inspector-node-popup");
    this.lastNodemenuItem = this.nodemenu.lastChild;
    this._setupNodeMenu = this._setupNodeMenu.bind(this);
    this._resetNodeMenu = this._resetNodeMenu.bind(this);
    this.nodemenu.addEventListener("popupshowing", this._setupNodeMenu, true);
    this.nodemenu.addEventListener("popuphiding", this._resetNodeMenu, true);

    // Create an empty selection
    this._selection = new Selection(this.walker);
    this.onNewSelection = this.onNewSelection.bind(this);
    this.selection.on("new-node-front", this.onNewSelection);
    this.onBeforeNewSelection = this.onBeforeNewSelection.bind(this);
    this.selection.on("before-new-node-front", this.onBeforeNewSelection);
    this.onDetached = this.onDetached.bind(this);
    this.selection.on("detached-front", this.onDetached);

    this.breadcrumbs = new HTMLBreadcrumbs(this);

    if (this.target.isLocalTab) {
      this.browser = this.target.tab.linkedBrowser;
      this.scheduleLayoutChange = this.scheduleLayoutChange.bind(this);
      this.browser.addEventListener("resize", this.scheduleLayoutChange, true);

      // Show a warning when the debugger is paused.
      // We show the warning only when the inspector
      // is selected.
      this.updateDebuggerPausedWarning = function() {
        let notificationBox = this._toolbox.getNotificationBox();
        let notification = notificationBox.getNotificationWithValue("inspector-script-paused");
        if (!notification && this._toolbox.currentToolId == "inspector" &&
            this.target.isThreadPaused) {
          let message = this.strings.GetStringFromName("debuggerPausedWarning.message");
          notificationBox.appendNotification(message,
            "inspector-script-paused", "", notificationBox.PRIORITY_WARNING_HIGH);
        }

        if (notification && this._toolbox.currentToolId != "inspector") {
          notificationBox.removeNotification(notification);
        }

        if (notification && !this.target.isThreadPaused) {
          notificationBox.removeNotification(notification);
        }

      }.bind(this);
      this.target.on("thread-paused", this.updateDebuggerPausedWarning);
      this.target.on("thread-resumed", this.updateDebuggerPausedWarning);
      this._toolbox.on("select", this.updateDebuggerPausedWarning);
      this.updateDebuggerPausedWarning();
    }

    this.highlighter = new Highlighter(this.target, this, this._toolbox);
    let button = this.panelDoc.getElementById("inspector-inspect-toolbutton");
    this.onLockStateChanged = function() {
      if (this.highlighter.locked) {
        button.removeAttribute("checked");
        this._toolbox.raise();
      } else {
        button.setAttribute("checked", "true");
      }
    }.bind(this);
    this.highlighter.on("locked", this.onLockStateChanged);
    this.highlighter.on("unlocked", this.onLockStateChanged);

    this._initMarkup();
    this.isReady = false;

    this.once("markuploaded", function() {
      this.isReady = true;

      // All the components are initialized. Let's select a node.
      this._selection.setNodeFront(defaultSelection);

      this.markup.expandNode(this.selection.nodeFront);

      this.emit("ready");
      deferred.resolve(this);
    }.bind(this));

    this.setupSearchBox();
    this.setupSidebar();

    return deferred.promise;
  },

  _onBeforeNavigate: function() {
    this._defaultNode = null;
    this.selection.setNodeFront(null);
    this._destroyMarkup();
    this.isDirty = false;
  },

  _getWalker: function() {
    return this.inspector.getWalker().then(walker => {
      this.walker = walker;
      return this.inspector.getPageStyle();
    }).then(pageStyle => {
      this.pageStyle = pageStyle;
    });
  },

  ...
```

I didn't see this Promise documented anywhere in the [Addon APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs), is there any documentation (or even source comments) on what this is, and how it is used?

Could it be used to add special styling or append some icons to certain elements in the DOM tree view of the Firefox DevTools Inspector?

Comment: [core/promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/core_promise)

Comment: @paa Thanks, but I read about Promise, that makes sense but I still don't know what exactly the Walker promise does.

Comment: [The WalkerActor is the client's view of the debuggee's DOM.  It's gives the client a tree of NodeActor objects](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/devtools/server/actors/inspector.js), very handy for remote targets.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever "walker" is mentioned in the devtools code, it usually refers to the **WalkerActor** class in toolkit/devtools/server/actors/inspector.js.

Actors are javascript classes that are specifically made to get information from the currently inspected page and context or manipulate them.

The UI part of the tools you see as a user don't do that directly. Indeed, the devtools use a client-server protocol to communicate between the toolbox (that hosts all of the panels you use) and the actors that run as part of the page being inspected. This is what allows to use the tools to inspect remote devices.

When it comes to the WalkerActor in particular, its role is to traverse the DOM tree and give information about nodes to the inspector-panel so that it can be displayed in the tools.

What you see when you open the devtools inspector on a page is a part of the DOM tree (a part only because it's not entirely expanded and collapsed nodes haven't been retrieved yet) that has been retrieved by the WalkerActor and sent (via the protocol) to the inspector panel.

The actual UI rendering of the panel is done *on the client-side* (which means, the toolbox side, in comparison with the actors/page side), in browser/devtools/markupview/markup-view.js

In this file, MarkupView and MarkupContainer classes in particular are responsible for displaying nodes. They're not specifically part of the Addons API, but it should be relatively easy to get hold of them since privileged code has access to the `gDevTools` global variable:

```
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/devtools/Loader.jsm");
let target = devtools.TargetFactory.forTab(gBrowser.selectedTab);
let toolbox = gDevTools.getToolbox(target);
let inspectorPanel = toolbox.getPanel("inspector");
inspector.markup // Returns the instance of MarkupView that is currently loaded in the inspector
```

Comment: Wow cool, is there a "FireShark" or addon that tells what is sent / what is sending and receiving in this protocol?

Comment: Not that I know of, but if you start Firefox from the command line (i.e on Mac `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox`) and then enable the pref `devtools.debugger.log` in about:config, you'll see all json packets being sent and received over the wire.